# Using Google Web Fonts With Gatsby and Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am using `createGlobalStyle` from styled-components and things work as they should as far as global styling is concerned. However, I am not able to use/apply Google fonts.

Here's the code:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`

  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@400;700&display=swap"); 
  
  body {
    font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  }

`
```

I also tried:

```
*{
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/)?

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      `Manrope: 400, 700`,
    ],
    display: `swap`,
  },
},
```

Your fonts will be loaded and you will be able to:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle` 
  body {
    font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  }
`
```